# CakePHP: Call to a member function set() on a non-object error

Tags: php, database, cakephp

My controller seems to be buggy here:

```
public function addAdmin($id) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    $this->User->set('role','admin');
    $this->User->save();
}
```

So it throws me the error `Call to a member function set() on a non-object`.

Actually, I want to update the field 'role' in a table column called 'role' and set it to 'admin'.

Can you imagine what's wrong? I've seen many tutorials using this with success but here apparently i'm missing something.

PS: I'm a cakephp newbie :D

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That `addAdmin` action is in UsersController.php ?

Comment: Could you post more code? Preferably the entire controller.

Comment: this is my entire AdminsController: http://pastie.org/private/ae1d1y7d9rfx8pmwyuaaa

Answer (score 2):

The `User` model isn't loaded.

Try loading it:

```
public function addAdmin($id) {
    $this->loadModel('User'); // here
    $this->User->id = $id;
    $this->User->set('role','admin');
    $this->User->save();
}
```

You don't have to load a model if you're in the Controller of that Model - but in this case, you're in a different Controller, so you either need to load the model (like above), or access it via an already-loaded associated model.

So, as an example, if you're in the RolesController, you could access the associated 'User' model without having to specifically load it:

```
$this->Role->User->set('role', 'admin');
```

Comment: also tried that in my code,but this do not work :(
The field in my database remains the same..

Comment: Are you still getting the error?  If not, then what you're asking is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Seen your code, your calling `User` from AdminsController.

Unless you do a

```
var $uses = array('Admin', 'User');
```

on the beggining of the controller (don't do it though, it affects performance), it won't recognize your User model. By default AdminsController only has direct access (that is, using $this->Admin) to Admin model, FoosController to Foo model (with $this->Foo), etc.

You can do as @Dave indicates in his answer, but do have in mind, if Admin is related (with hasMany, belongsTo, or any other association) with the User model, then you can access the User model from the AdminsController like this

```
$this->Admin->User->set(1,2);
```

And if you have a Foo model associated with User, for example, the same concatenation rule applies, and in your AdminsController you can do

```
$this->Admin->User->Foo('find')
```

(A lot of concatenation like this affects performance).

Comment: depends on how your models are related, are they? Does the error change at least?

Comment: yeah,now there is a fatal error:Call to a member function set() on a non-object at the new line

Comment: as Dave said,this is the answer to this question and the new problem i face is a totally new question..

Answer (score 0):

loadModel works for me! I initially tried using a model function that called two different models but instead I created a a model function for each model and then called functions in a single controller.

```
            if ($this->Transaction->saveTrans(PARAMETERS)){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Transaction Success!'));
            $this->loadModel('Creditcard');
            if ($this->Creditcard->saveCC(PARAMETERS)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Credit Card Success!'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unsuccessful: The Credit Card was approved but could not be saved. Please try again.'));
            }
```